# Validate if any changes were made in TabPage

Tags: vb.net, dirty-data

So I'm wondering if someone can give me a good idea how to do something. I have a tabControl in my application - I load up a page - TabPage1 - with about 25-30 fields. On loading all the data - i run a loop to save each control value to .tag.  I also have a function called isDirty() that basically checks each control's ctr.tag.tostring <> ctr.text. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to build a quick handler to check all controls on the form. I tried using TagPage1.Validating, however that doesn't do anything.

my isDirty() function looks like this...

```
    Private Function isDirty() As Boolean

    isDirty = False

    For Each ctr As Control In TabPage1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctr Is TextBox And ctr.Enabled = True Then
            If ctr.Tag.ToString <> ctr.Text Then
                isDirty = True
            End If
        End If
        'more if statements for comboboxes and such
      Next
    End Function
```

I'm hoping to be able to plug this function in somewhere and do a CALL on it something like

```
 if isDirty() then
    MsgBox "You have made a change to this form"
 End if
```

Do i have to call this on each control's selection changed?

Comment: The NET provider and helper objects will do *all* that for you.  And if they didnt, I'd take an OOP approach and have a class (Cust, Order, Eno...whatever) whch tracked changes, or an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches

1. When most of the controls do not have change event handler, your approach seems to be correct. By the way, in your above code you missed `Exit For`, after `isDirty = True`.
2. When most of the controls have changed event handler implemented(this will be the case if in your design you have data models/objects), rather than checking changes in a loop, I would prefer to check when the change is made. I mean to say declare a form level variable `bool changed`. Controls like `textbox`, `combobox`, `radiobutton`, `checkbox`, etc.. mostly have their change event handlers, if the change is made set `changed` to `True`.

Comment: I understand i was just trying ti find a way to do it in one event handler, kinda like _validating evemt i think i might try that